# How can I determine whether a unit is in range or not?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm programming a small game that's going to be somewhat like a tower defence. I was playing around with how I determin whether a unit is in range or not.

```
public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
    {
        Timer -= theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (Timer < 0)
        {
            bool CreateNew = true;
            foreach (Unit theUnit in Lists.ennemyUnits)
            {
                if (Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(Vector2.Distance(Location, theUnit.Location)),2) < 999);
                {
                    foreach (Arrow theArrow in Quiver)
                    {
                        if(theArrow.visible == false)
                        {
                            CreateNew = false;

                            theArrow.shootProjectile(Location, theUnit.Location);

                            Timer = 3;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    if (CreateNew == true)
                    {
                        Arrow theArrow = new Arrow();
                        Quiver.Add(theArrow);

                        Timer = 3;

                        theArrow.shootProjectile(Location, theUnit.Location);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm running into a problem with this, when the location of my archer in Y is higher or the X is lower the archer doesn't shoot the enemy unit. I do not understand why?

Comment: You have a semicolon after the if, meaning it will always execute the shooting logic.

Comment: Edit: the problem must be located in the shootProjectile method, which I will add after I revised it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only the distance, without use the sqrt and the Pow because the distance is usually calculate with this formula:

```
float dist(vector3d v1, v2)
{
    v.x = v1.x - v2.x;
    v.y = v1.y - v2.y;
    v.z = v1.z - v2.z;
    return sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y + v.z*v.z);
}
```

as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

Comment: I did this because I wanted to make sure it's not negative, but as you just said the method makes always makes sure it's like that. This doesn't solve the real problem though. thanks for you response anyway

Comment: Have you tried without the pow and the sqrt? I suggeste them because maybe they are the cause of the problem...

Comment: I tried it without the pow and sqrt just now and it still gives me the same problem.

Comment: Ok, try to debug this snippet, assign a variable the result of the distance operation and see the result...

Comment: I did what you asked and doing so I realize that my bug must be located in the shootProjectilemethod. I'll edit it in after I revised it myself.

Comment: Please don't; if you are going to ask about a different problem / different portion of code, post a new question. This answer addresses your original question (determining if a unit is within some range). If you drastically alter your question it invalidates the answer, and potentially turns your question into a "debug my code" question, which is offtopic.

Comment: ok thank then I will not do so, I will accept this answer so LaboPie get's something out of it too.

Comment: There already is a built in method in XNA for getting the length of a vector, namely .Length(). Use LengthSquared() if performance is an issue.